# How to wait for threads spawned from a spring-scheduler to complete?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-scheduled

I am using spring-scheduler and spawning multiple threads from the `@Scheduled` method (one of them has a rest call). 
**Whats the best way to wait in the `@Scheduled` method for all threads to complete and then exit?**

**Application details:** I have a scheduled task wherein I get a list single type of object (say Class Order) from the DB, divide them into chunks (So if I get 5000 Orders, I will divide into 5 chunks of 1000 each). Then I loop over every chunk and for every Order in the chunk I get a list of Products from the `Order` and then loop over them. For every Product I need to make a rest call to another service which returns a value (e.g. price) which I need to set in this product. This is scheduled to be done every 1 hour (configurable).

**What I have thought so far:** In the scheduler, call a `UpdatePriceJobs` execute method. This methods first divides the list into chunks. Each chunk is then processed by a `ChunkProcessor` by its process method. The process method is annotated with spring @Async so that each chunk is processed in a separate thread. Then it calls the process method on the productProcessor service which makes the rest call. This method is again annotated with `@Async`. So idea is to run `Chunks` in parallel and then make parallel price update calls. As you can see I will have to wait for all the threads to finish otherwise some products will not get the updated prices.

First thing that I thought of was a countdown latch. However, I will have to pass it around in order to decrement the counter and second will have to calculate the number of threads that will be created.

```
@Override
public void process(Chunk<Order> chunk) {
    final List<Chunk<Order>> chunks = orderChunkProvider.getChunks(items);
    for (final Chunk<Order> chunk : chunks) {
        OrderChunkProcessor.process(chunk);
    }
```

}

```
@Async
@Override
public void process(Chunk<Order> chunk) {
    final List<Order> orders = chunk.getItems();
    for (final Order order : orders ) {
        final List<Product> products = order.getProductss();
        for (final Product product : products ) {
            productProcessor.process(product);
        }
 }
```

`productProcessor.process(product)` method makes the rest call and is also annotated with `@Async`

What is the best way to wait for all the threads created? Or is the design entirely flawed and some big changes would be required.

PS: I cannot use spring-batch as we use a NoSql database which doesn't support transactions and spring-batch doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Fork/Join` framework in java.`Fork/Join` is a parallel processing framework.First,you can only set parallel level don't need to figure out how many thread do you need.Second, there ia method `awaitTermination` can block current thread until process finish,so you no need use `CountDownLatch`. If you decide to use `Fork/Join` this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-fork-join) can help you.

Attention,`@Async` just use a thread pool to execute task，if task need more time may influences other task.

Comment: ForkJoinPool seem to have many problems : http://coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html

Comment: If you don't use other professional libraries, i thing use Fork/join is a good choice,you can try to manage this task.